# Permission denied when trying to SCP from jenkins docker container to apache host

Tags: docker, apache, jenkins, permissions

I'm trying to configure a simple Jenkinsfile pipeline to take a new commit from github then deploy an updated index.html from jenkins-cloned repo to apache's /public_html folder. Architecture is as follows:

- *Docker container running jenkins; with jenkins being run by default jenkins user in jenkins group*
- *Docker hosted on lubuntu VM which also has apache installed as default root user in www-data
  group*
- *I added (my) host_user to www-data via: sudo usermod -a -G www-data hostuser*
- *I set public_html to rwx rwx r x via: sudo chmod 775 /var/www//tutorialJenkins_test/public_html*
- *I setup ssh between container and host (container storing private key; generated
  in container as jenkins user; and host storing public key in its .ssh/authorized_keys file*

As a result:

1. *host_user in lubuntu host can cp a file to public_html*
2. *jenkins user in docker container can scp a file to e.g. /home/hostuser/*
3. *Although jenkins build is successful, I get *'**permission denied**'*, when trying to get jenkins user to scp to the public-html folder.*

Any ideas?

- I tried adding a new user named jenkins to apache's www-data group but not only this didn't work, I assume this is not seen as being the same actual user that's in the docker container?
- I also assume chmod 777 to public_html is not an ideal?

My jenkinsfile is written as follows:

```
pipeline{
    agent any
        stages {
            stage("build") {
                steps {
                    script {
                        try {
                            // SSH copy index.html from the jenkins-cloned repo in the docker container, to the docker host:
                            sh 'scp index.html hostuser@[host_ip]:/var/www/tutorialJenkins_test/public_html'
                        } catch (err) {
                                echo "File copy to localhost failed: ${err}"
                                // handle exception..
                            } finally {
                                echo "Build stage complete.."
                            }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A 777 permission on the directory means that everyone has access to read/write/execute (execute on a directory means that you can do an ls of the directory). 755 means read and execute access for everyone and also write access for the owner of the file.
So after reading your question... I can help you in 3 ways.

1. Simply give 777 (But Lol I think you don't want this)
2. So my 2nd way: make Jenkins owner of that path... with 755 it would be able to move.
3. This answer is best of all that I can give you: BUT I am assuming your Jenkins have sudo access... if not then you have to give Jenkins a sudo access.
   See, if you are reading this then you don't want to give 777 every time nor do you want Jenkins to be owner every time.

(As you said "jenkins user in docker container can scp a file to e.g. /home/hostuser/") What you can do is -->
Till where Jenkins can copy... scp it, then in Jenkins pom file write command to run a shell file

```
stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                // Execute the shell script
                sh './test.sh'

            }
        }
    }
```

And in shell file

1. First Change permission to 777 using sudo or change owner (any one)
2. Move the File
3. Revert back changes of permission/owner

Like

```
sudo chmod -R 777 dirPath
sudo mv folder dirPath
sudo chmod -R 775 dirPath
```

OR

```
sudo chown -R newUser:newGroup dirPath
sudo mv folder dirPath
sudo chown -R oldUser:oldGroup dirPath
```

Like this you will change permission > Move and then > Revert Permission.

Comment: Mate thanks for your input, as you helped me realize that my public_html was owned by root but needed to be owned by my user (website owner). So I ran: 

chown -R [hostuser]:[hostuser group] [domain folder] 

after which, jenkins was able to access this [domain folder]/public_html to drop the newly-cloned index.html file into (as I'd already configured SSH between the jenkins user and hostuser). 

Cheers